# Interpolate based on group

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to perform an interpolation based on the input data ( test_data_Inputs) on the test_data data frame. The way I have it set up now is I do it by Peril so so I first created a dataframe that only contained the fire peril (see below) then perform the interpolation on that specific peril group:

The goal is to have a column in the test_data_inputs that has both the Peril Type, and Factor. One of the issues I have been encountering is the situation where the amount of insurance in the test_data_input is a perfect match within the test_data dataframe. It still interpolates regardless of if it is a perfect match or not.

```
fire_peril_test=test_data[test_data['Peril Type'=='Fire']]
from scipy import interpolate
x=fire_peril_test['Amount of Insurance']
x=fire_peril_test['Amount Of Insurance']
y=_fire_peril_test['Factor']
y=fire_peril_test['Factor']
f=interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
xnew=test_data_Inputs["Amount of Insurance"]
ynew=f(xnew)


test_data_Inputs=pd.DataFrame({'Amount of Insurance':[320000,330000,340000]})
test_data=pd.DataFrame({'Amount of Insurance':[300000,350000,400000,300000,350000,400000],'Peril Type':['Fire','Fire','Fire','Water','Water','Water'],'Factor':[.10,.20,.35,.20,.30,.40]})
```

Appreciate all of the assistance.

Comment: Do a `groupby` on the dataframe and interpolate

Comment: Not sure how that would work if my input data is a separate dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
amount_of_insurance=pd.DataFrame()
df['Amount of Insurance']=pd.melt(df['Amount of Insurance'],id_vars=['Amount Of Insurance'],var_name='Peril Type',value_name='Factor')

for peril in df['Amount of Insurance']['Peril Type'].unique():
    #peril='Fire'
    x=df['Amount of Insurance']['Amount Of Insurance'][df['Amount of Insurance']['Peril Type']==str(peril)]
    y=df['Amount of Insurance']['Factor'][df['Amount of Insurance']['Peril Type']==str(peril)]
    f=interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
    xnew=data_for_rater[['Enter Amount of Insurance']]
    ynew=f(xnew)
    append_frame=data_for_rater[['Group','Enter Amount of Insurance']]
    append_frame['Peril Type']=str(peril)
    append_frame['Factor']=ynew
    amount_of_insurance=amount_of_insurance.append(append_frame)
```

My solution with my actual data. Pretty much I melted the data to be able to loop through the unique Peril Types. If you guys have any alternatives let me know...